# Will a shared_ptr automatically free up memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr

I need to use a shared_ptr here because I can't change the API.

```
Foo1 *foo1 = new Foo1(...);
shared_ptr<Foo2> foo2(foo1);
```

Is the shared_ptr here going to handle freeing the memory used by foo1? If I understand correctly, I shouldn't have to call delete on foo1 correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct - that's the whole point of `shared_ptr`. I don't understand why you're not using `shared_ptr<Foo2> = new Foo1` though.

Comment: When the `shared_ptr`'s reference count hits 0, it will destruct the `Foo1` object it holds, but if you allocate memory in the `Foo1` object, you have to make sure the destructor behaves as you expect.

Comment: How are the types Foo1 and Foo2 related? There had better be a valid conversion between the two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. You are correct, but the correct way to initialise `foo2` is:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo2> foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo1>();
```

Herb Sutter discusses the reasons why you should use `std::make_shared<>()` here:
https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Comment: Note that this also discusses reasons to **not** use `std::make_shared`.

Comment: I've updated the link to point to Herb Sutter's GotW#103 instead, as that gives a better breakdown of what the function actually does.

Comment: The original link had a more complete analysis of when to use and **when not to use** `std::make_shared`. The new link only says that `std::make_shared` is wonderful.

Comment: Herb Sutter's link has been updated. Here's the new permanent link: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't call delete on foo1.

Better you shouldn't create foo1. Only foo2:

```
shared_ptr<Foo2> foo2(new Foo1(...));
```

- std::shared_ptr: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

> std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer.

If you do not need this pointer to be shared - consider to use `std::unique_ptr`

- std::unique_ptr: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

> std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that: retains sole ownership of an
>   object through a pointer, and destroys the pointed-to object when the
>   unique_ptr goes out of scope.

Comment: Excellent suggestion to not create foo1.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The smart pointers provide ownership semantics. In particular, the semantics provided by `std::shared_ptr` are such that the object will be deleted once the last `shared_ptr` pointing to it is destroyed. `shared_ptr` keeps a reference count (how many `shared_ptr`s are referring to the object) and when it reaches 0, it deletes the object.